# The tagging on Minecraft mod questions is a mess

Tags: discussion, tags

As many of you are well aware, we have a giant mess of tags related to Minecraft mods. (and if you're not aware, here's a short list: [minecraft-forge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-forge) [minecraft-feed-the-beast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-feed-the-beast) [minecraft-ae](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-ae) [minecraft-thaumcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-thaumcraft) [minecraft-comes-alive](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-comes-alive) [yogscast-complete-pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yogscast-complete-pack) [minecraft-oceancraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-oceancraft)). It is a mess.

How do we want to go about tagging questions relating to Minecraft mods?

Answer (score 8):

I would like to pose that yes, the current situation isn't ideal but, bar a little tidy up, it's okay.

Here's how I see it: Tags are useful in a number of ways, primarily around filtering content. I can subscribe to a tag, or filter it out, or make it a favourite. For this reason, tags should aim to cater to areas of expertise.

Minecraft is a pretty special case amongst games given the enormous breadth and depth of mods out there, and the extensive modding community. Not to mention [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) is the biggest tag on the site. Feed the Beast and other modpacks are made wildly popular by channels such as the Yogscast. Clearly these are things people want to search by, filter by etc.

I propose the following *loose* guidelines:

- Remove [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods). I can't think of a good reason for this to exist (although if someone can suggest a question that is about mods in general where this might be appropriate I'm happy to change my mind)
- Tag mods as we do, e.g. [minecraft-buildcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-buildcraft)
- Tag modpacks as we do too, e.g. [minecraft-feedthebeast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-feedthebeast)
- Use all appropriate tags for a question.

These feels kinda *icky* because we're used to having only one tag on a question at any one time, and having 3 or 4 feels a bit wrong, but I believe in this case it's justified.

Comment: What about mods (or packs) that aren't currently tagged or are unlikely to see much use? Wouldn't keeping minecfaft-mods around for that be appropriate? Some could be tagged with forge or FTB, but would that cover all of them?

Comment: @MBraedley We tag games with one question, why not mods?

Comment: Yes, that is fair. I guess my biggest concern is is if someone can't create a tag and it's not immediately obvious to others that it should be there. Besides, we have platform tags as a tag of last resort for a reason.

Comment: The tag [tag:minecraft] is always available, and someone can swoop in and create more tags if necessary.

Comment: I think we should also rename the yogscast one to [minecraft-yogscast-pack], to match the other tags

Answer (score 0):

I propose dropping all specific Minecraft mod tags (or synonymizing them) and pointing them at [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods). I think we should still specify that a question is talking about a modded game, however, we should follow the convention that other moddable games follow and not have a tag for every single mod out there.

I'm also now opposed to [minecraft-feed-the-beast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-feed-the-beast), simply because Feed The Beast has expanded a lot since the time the tag has been used; it was originally around 3 packs, with similar mods each, now, there are a couple dozen packs on the FTB launcher. The tag itself doesn't disambiguate anything, it just creates a potential for messy tagging.

Comment: This is a step too far IMO, and far too prescriptive. Some mods have many questions, and so a tag is appropriate, e.g. [minecraft-buildcraft](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-buildcraft). Minecraft is a game unlike most others when it comes to modding. "A foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds".

Comment: The first paragraph is not a good idea, as mentioned by @fredley, getting rid of minecraft-feed-the-beast would be good, although we'd need something for issues that span multiple mods.