# Tag synonym suggestion [tinkers-construct] -> [minecraft-tinkers-construct]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request, tag-merging

After concluding that Unionhawk is correct and [The tagging on Minecraft mod questions is a mess](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/the-tagging-on-minecraft-mod-questions-is-a-mess), I thought I'd go about tidying them up a little. Going by Fredly's upvoted answer, we want to get rid of the [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) tag on questions which relate to specific mods, and retag them with more relevant tags (e.g. as we have done with [minecraft-feed-the-beast](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-feed-the-beast) etc.).

In an effort to maintain consistency I suggest that we keep tags for Minectaft mods in the format of [minecraft-mod-name] and therefore recommend that we synonymise the tag [tinkers-construct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tinkers-construct) and [minecraft-tinkers-construct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-tinkers-construct) and replace the former with the latter.

Unfortunately I can't make the tag synonym request in the default way because I don't have any rep in the tag, so I've come to you, meta, to ask for your assistance.

Comment: Cannot perform this merge: a tag cannot be longer than 25 characters

Comment: Oh, bah humbug. Maybe mc-tinkers-construct then, as we've done for expansions etc. in the past? (e.g. Assassin's Creed = ac)

Comment: Intended to ping @fredley in my previous comment....

Comment: Yeah I'm happy with that approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've migrated the tag to [mc-tinkers-construct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mc-tinkers-construct).