# Tag synonym suggestion [bukkit-worldedit] to [minecraft-bukkit-worldedit]

Tags: support, retag-request, tag-merging

In exactly the same vein as my [previous question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10045/tag-synonym-suggestion-tinkers-construct-minecraft-tinkers-construct), I would like to suggest that we migrate and synonym-ise [bukkit-worldedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bukkit-worldedit) to [minecraft-bukkit-worldedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bukkit-worldedit) (or if that exceeds the character limit, to [mc-bukkit-worldedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mc-bukkit-worldedit)