# Rename the [bukkit-worldedit] tag to [minecraft-worldedit]? (It doesn't just support Bukkit)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, minecraft

As part of the Tag Wiki edit post I stumbled across [bukkit-worldedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bukkit-worldedit). Now it was proposed [just over a year ago](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10052/28182) to rename it to [minecraft-bukkit-worldedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-bukkit-worldedit) however - according to [WorldEdit's Wiki page](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit) WorldEdit **also** supports the Forge, LiteLoader, Canary and hMod modding platforms - not just Bukkit.

Would it then be prudent to remove 'bukkit' from the tag and simply rename it [minecraft-worldedit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-worldedit)? This will also bring it in line with the other `[minecraft-*]` tags, as it is currently the only one that starts with 'bukkit'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems sensible to me, tags merged.