# Should questions about Minecraft mods be tagged mods?

Tags: discussion, tags, minecraft, sub-tags

I know Minecraft mod questions should be tagged [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods).

Should they also be tagged [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods)? That seems redundant, but should tags look like this:

[minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods)

Or this:

[minecraft-java-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-java-edition) [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods)

I’d prefer the first but is there an “official” guideline on that?

Comment: Related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15559/258509 | Also Related: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10001/258509

Answer (score 3):

Well, there are certain aspects of the [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) tag, since it is ambiguous and usually used in other topics that doesn't seem to have their mod tag.

In my preference, it is better to just use the first option, because I only need tags showing that I have a question on a Minecraft mod and I don't need an additional [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods) tag.

But should we burninate [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) in favor of [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods)? It would depend on the community, to be honest.

Comment: Either way I don't think burning [tag:minecraft-mods] would be a great idea personally

Comment: Minecraft is out of my area of expertise, but I agreed with Penguin on not burning it as a tag; it doesn't really fit the [criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/201625). If anything were to be done to `minecraft-mods`, it'd probably be better to make it a synonym of `mods`