# All [minecraft-mods] are [mods]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, minecraft

[**@Penguin**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/258509/penguin) asked [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15547/should-questions-about-minecraft-mods-be-tagged-mods) on the meta and I answered it, where I specified this:

> But should we burninate [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) in favor of [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods)? It would depend on the community, to be honest.

Then [**@Wondercricket**](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/124566/wondercricket) commented thinking about making [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) a synonym to [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods), since they're the same topic, but the other is in Minecraft.

It doesn't have to be burninated, but it can be turned into [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods)'s tag synonym because it seems like having 2 tags of the same topic can just be merged into 1.

So in your opinion, should we make [minecraft-mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-mods) a tag synonym of [mods](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mods)?

Comment: I also did say that Minecraft is out of my area of expertise, so I merely gave my 2 cents for another option :) Those who are familiar in the realm of Minecraft would probably have a better say in the matter

Comment: How does making tags synonyms work? Could you still filter the Minecraft posts if we made them synonyms? Personally, I feel there should still be a distinction for Minecraft mods since there are so many. In my opinion, [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10000/264353) is an important point. That whole question ad answer line is a good point to start at.

Comment: @Potterton, making a tag a synonym means that any time someone uses the tag minecraft-mods, it would be changed to mods instead, and all current questions with minecraft-mods tag would instead have mods tag now

Comment: @Dragonrage That makes sense, but could someone like me filter the minecraft-mods out of the mods tag once they are synonyms? I don't think we should make them synonyms unless we could do that?

Comment: @Potterton as far as I know, you wouldn’t be able to do that, no

Comment: @potterton you could with the search query `[mods] [minecraft-java-edition]`

Comment: @Potterton i dont think it actually pinged you last time because of the capitalization error, so i saw it again and here it is - 3 weeks late - take a look at my last message

Comment: @Penguin No worries! The only issue with that is the fact that not all askers put the Java Edition tag (as evident from the discussion here with commands https://meta.arqade.com/q/15612/264353 ) So what would we do there?

Comment: @Potterton when its obviously about minecraft, me or other people with 2k rep for editing just usually edit it in