# Tag rename request [yogscast-complete-pack] -> [minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-rename-request

[yogscast-complete-pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yogscast-complete-pack)'s name really just doesn't make sense. I'm guessing it was just created by someone and then that was it's name, but shouldn't it be called [minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack)?

I just saw that [@Robotnik](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28182) has [said this a while ago](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10001/258509) and I don't think there's any reason not to, so why don't we?

Comment: This is probably one of those names that predates the increase of the tag name limit to 25 to 35 characters in August 2017. there should be no reason not to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Done!

```
updating post history, 11 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 9 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack' doesn't exist, renaming 'yogscast-complete-pack' to 'minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack] and [yogscast-complete-pack] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym yogscast-complete-pack -> minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack was approved!
```